# Error googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, CI-CD pipeline of azure devops throws error while uploading app to playstore

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, google-play, azure-pipelines

Getting 403 forbidden while running the CI-CD release pipeline from Azure DevOps to uploading android app to play store by automating the process. 
[image]

I have configured access and enabled `Google play developer API` and given all permission as well still not able to connect to the play store.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue I added

> service account email

to play store console which is generated while configuring api access and enabling `Google play developer API`  and then you need to link that email to the project from API ACCESS menu in play store console.